# Django Rosetta DjangoUnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

I'm getting following error using django rosetta (version 0.7.6) when I click to the language I want to start translating. It's Debian server with apache. I think this error is caused by some of the translation strings. However, I can't simulate this error on local server (using OS X) and in other programs for translation .POs can be opened without problem.

Thank you for any help.

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/rosetta/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rosetta/views.py", line 282, in home
    ), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 45, in render_to_response
    using=using)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 115, in render_to_string
    template_name, context, context_instance, dirs, dictionary)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 221, in render_to_string
    return t.render(context_instance)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 963, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 940, in render_value_in_context
    value = force_text(value)
  File "/home/project/www/deploy/apache/main/../../../deploy/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 102, in force_text
    raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)
DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128). You passed in <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7f3b054235d0> (<class 'django.utils.functional.__proxy__'>)
```